# Multiple-R from just b coefficients

Tags: r, multiple-regression, r-squared, effect-size, multiple-imputation

Packages from my preferred software (`Amelia` and `Zelig` from R) give me estimates of a linear model after multiple imputation, but do not provide multiple R. Is there a way to calculate multiple-R from just the b coefficients? Below is the overall model provided through `Zelig`.

```
            Estimate Std.Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.37911   1.18224  -1.167 2.434e-01    
visual       0.31960   0.05857   5.456 4.858e-08 ***
mosaic       0.06534   0.02318   2.818 4.826e-03   *
grades       0.71839   0.18109   3.967 7.278e-05 ***
mathgr       1.79173   0.46944   3.817 1.352e-04  **
alg          2.06293   0.61276   3.367 7.610e-04  **
alg2         2.00871   0.54415   3.691 2.230e-04  **
geo          2.55879   0.55714   4.593 4.375e-06 ***
trig         0.98196   0.60712   1.617 1.058e-01    
calc         2.33114   0.80124   2.909 3.621e-03   *
faed         0.18234   0.09029   2.020 4.343e-02   .
maed        -0.12921   0.10443  -1.237 2.160e-01    
sex          1.50875   0.41893   3.601 3.165e-04  **
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to calculate multiple R2 just from the estimated coefficients $b$, because the multiple R2 also depends on the distribution of the predictors $x$. And, if you change the distribution of $x$, it can vary a lot!